# SQL Insert & Update Options

Tags: sql, insert, sql-update, insert-update

Ok, so I need some SQL 101 assistance. I am building a new table in SQL that will be used in a VPN connection to an outside source.  I have built a view inside of SQL that contains all the information I need from the main database for this new table.  I now need to push the data into the table.  The problem is that the data is constantly changing and I am not really sure what my easiest way to do this is.  I need to be able to copy the data from the view to the table initially but after that I need to be able to update already existing records with new information and insert new records into the table that don't already exist.

Now, the reason I am not just using the view to deal with the data needed through the VPN is because the outside source that will be using the data needs to be able to push back some values that don't exist anywhere in my table and save them to the unique records they are associated with.  When I do the update, I need to leave those values that are pushed back alone and just update the values that already exist in my database.

I hope this makes sense as I need some guidance on how to do this as I have not done this before.

The table for this looks like this:

```
ID       Name          Address     Email        X       Y     Z<br>
123456   John Smith    123 Any St  john@d.com   123     12    1125
```

X Y & Z are the fields that will be filled from an outside source which will be tied to the ID number of the record from the web service.

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: What SQL platform are you using?  SQL Server, Postgres, MySql, Oracle, other?

Comment: Its a bit unclear still what you want to do.  Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I am using SQL Server 2012.  

The data that you see, ID, Name, Address & email are all fields that exist in the database already and the view grabs.  X, Y & Z are fields that the table will have but are written to the table from the outside web service.  

What I need to know is how do I get the data from the view into the new table without deleting what is there, just updating what is there and if a record for said ID does not exist, add it to the table.